# Giving unique identifiers in fragments while using ViewPager FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-identifiers

I want to give each of my fragment a unique tag because they don't have id's (I'm using ViewPager) How can I do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager vp=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        vp.setAdapter(new Adapter(fragmentManager));
    }   
    public class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public Adapter (FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int a) {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            if(a==0) {
                fragment = new FragmentX();
            }
            if(a==1) {
                fragment = new FragmentY();
            }
                        if(a==2) {
                fragment = new FragmentZ();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

I'm a newbie on this java/android language. So just go easy on me. It'd be good if you'll answer me with code. Thank you.

Comment: there is a lot and a lot of documentation and posts abut the viewpager. Have you already go through all that ? [here](https://www.google.fr/search?q=viewpager+tag+fragment&oq=viewpager+with+tag&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.5611j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) [there is in first line](http://tamsler.blogspot.fr/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html)

Comment: @Poutrathor - I've seen that blog but I don't know where did he get the mPageReferenceMap. Can you please edit my code and implement those codes in the link you've given?

Comment: mPageReferenceMap is a "map" object or any object of this family. These object links 2 things together, a key and a value; here, it's the index of your fragment and its tag (surname).

Answer (score 0):

Edit : if my comments are not enough to put you on the good path, here is my 2 cents for what they are worht as I am also a newbie.

The best thing you should do is to try your hands at demo projects. There are many demo project for Android. I recommend CommonsWare's work, for it is amazing. [Here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager) you will find several projects around the viewpager. From the link I gave you will find many many more project that will 99% show you a good implementation of ANY features you will need as a beginner/moderate coder.

To learn Android (this is what I am doing for 8 months now), I found that if you have no teacher, the best way is to find demo project and modify them and twisted them to really learn why and how things work.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks man. tried to upvote you but it says still needs reputation.

Comment: don't worry. Tell me if you fail at downloading some demos on your IDE, but once again getting a project from github is explained